# Deviance in hurdle model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

How can I calculate the deviance for the factors and the null and saturated models with Hurdle models?

I used the function `hurdle()` from the package `pscl`. The functions `anova()` or `deviance()` are not applicable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the hurdle and zero-inflation models are both composed of two submodels they do not have all the properties of classical GLMs (generalized linear models) like the Poisson model. That's why we decided *not* to provide a `deviance()` or `anova()` method for `"hurdle"` and `"zeroinfl"` objects. Instead there is a `logLik()` method for extracting the log-likelihood (which is closely connected to the deviance in GLMs). For inference, functions like `lrtest()` from `lmtest` for the likelihood ratio test can be used. Further options are discussed in `vignette("countreg", package = "pscl")` (see e.g. the end of Section 2.2).